# Initializing std::complex

Tags: c++

I saw couple of examples online which shows that the std::complex variables can be initialized by the following:

```
std::complex<float> val(10, -2);
```

But, is there a way to do something like the following:

```
std::complex<float> val;
val.real = 10;
val.imag = -2;
```

Comment: http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/20-2.html

Comment: gcc allows val.real()=10 as an extension in C++03 mode but not in C++11 mode. The correct syntax is val.real(10); val.imag(-2);.

Comment: *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&val)=10 and reinterpret_cast<float*>(&val)[1]=-2 are also guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`std::complex::real`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/real) and [`std::complex::imag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/imag) are acutally functions. They can be used to either return the real / imaginary part as well as to set them, but still using the function call syntax by providing the value as an argument:

```
std::complex<float> val;
val.real(10);
val.imag(-2);
```

However, this is not called **initialization**. This changes the value of `val`, which has been initialized in the very first line of code with zero.

Effectively, you see the same result (after that code, `val` has the value you expect it to be), but requires some more instructions unless the compiler can optimize this away. Since `std::complex` is a standard type it's very good possible that the compiler will do that, but you can never be sure about this.